# isospectrality of Laplacian on interval

Tags: spectral-theory

Consider $-\frac{d^2}{d x^2}$ on an interval, say, [0,1]. Are there different boundary conditions of self-adjointness such that the spectrum is the same, including degeneracy? Any explicit example?

Comment: including degeneracy, right?

Comment: still, the spectral measure must be different among the two, correct?